# Neo4j sparql-plugin returns 500 error

Tags: neo4j

I have installed the sparql plugin for Neo4j (which has appeared in the extensions)

however when I run

```
:POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SPARQLPlugin/graphdb/insert_quad
{
  "s" : "http://neo4j.org#joe",
  "p" : "http://neo4j.org#knows",
  "o" : "http://neo4j.org#sara",
  "c" : "http://neo4j.org"
}
```

from the neo4j browser I get a 500 returned. (I am using Neo 2.0.0)

any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please share the logfiles under data/log and data/graph.db/messages.log and the body of the response if any

Comment: Hi Michael, below is the relevant section of log.
2014-06-21 09:28:00.141+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Mounted discovery module (org.neo4j.server.rest.discovery) at: /
2014-06-21 09:28:00.229+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Loaded server plugin "SPARQLPlugin" (org.neo4j.server.plugin.sparql.SPARQLPlugin)
2014-06-21 09:28:00.229+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:   GraphDatabaseService.insert_quad: execute a SPARQL query.
2014-06-21 09:28:00.230+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:   GraphDatabaseService.execute_sparql: execute a SPARQL query.

Comment: any stacktrace in `messages.log` ?

Comment: I can't find the messages.log file, does logging need to be configured?